# A way to use blender animations with pygame to export it to android

Tags: android, pygame, blender

Two mainly question about blender

1. Is there a way to use what is made using blender framework to use it on pygame so that it can be exported to android?
2. A way to export material from blender so that it can be used directly with an app on android.

P.D : i saw the blender page and some ways of doing this but all of them are on betas and so on....

Comment: what do you exactly want to export?

Comment: animations, textures, scenarios...etc...

Comment: ouh, that sounds really taugh...^^ btw, I used pygame, blender and android, I really mean it

Comment: you mean a blender game for android?

Comment: no, I mean that I wrote a few games with pygame, made some rendering with blender that had nothing to do with those games, and currently I'm programming android apps for others, according to my experience I'd say, what you want to do is really not trivial...!

Comment: well, from pygame you can create an apk ... maybe outthere is something similar for this combination :D